# Sonar Eclipse plugin : local analysis is still tagging fixed issues

Tags: eclipse-plugin, static-analysis, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm using the Sonar Eclipse plugin v3.3.

After I've fixed a rule violation, not a new issue, but one that exists on the sonar server, I re-run the analysis on my project in Eclipse.  I expected that the fixed issues would no longer be flagged by the analysis, but they appear to be still flagged even though they have been fixed.

In my Eclipse SonarQube preferences I have the severity marked as warning and Force full preview... unchecked.

In the view options I have Show->All Issues on Selection checked.

How do I set up the plugin so that once I've fixed the issue locally, the issue is no longer flagged when I re-run the analysis on my project?

**Edit**:
Full analysis is run nightly by a conditional build step in Jenkins using SonarQube Runner.

When I run the analysis via Eclipse, the first thing it does is wipe out the existing issue annotations, but then as soon as it contacts the server it immediately adds them back in.  The issues stay flagged regardless of whether they were fixed locally or not.

If I intentionally put in the wrong projectKey in the org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.prefs file, then the local analysis runs similar to what I would expect. It flags all existing issues as new, which is expected, since it can't reach the server to ask if they were preexisting. It doesn't flag any fixed issues.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I was using 3.7.3 on the server and not 4.0 or above.  I upgraded the server install to 4.1 and all is well now.

BTW - The Sonar console output clearly stated :

> SonarQube version 4.0 is required to perform local analysis.